# How to increase ramdisk size?

Tags: linux, ramdisk

I have created a ramdisk of 8 MB using the following commands:

```
mkfs -q /dev/ram1 8192
mkdir -p /ramcache
mount /dev/ram1 /ramcache
```

Now I want to increase the size of the ramdisk to 1.5 GB. How should I do it?

Comment: changing the first number to 1610612736?  i.e. 1.5gb in bytes. Or have I missed something?!?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a `tmpfs` rather than formatting a ram block device as a file system?

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=1500M tmpfs /ramcache
```

reduces the commands from three to one and limits the size to 1.5G.